Is this a valid probability density function?

$0\le\pi\le 1$, $\lambda > 0$.
One of the conditions for being a probability function is that $P(x=k)\ge 0$ for all k. However, we can see that in the second equation when $k >0$, because $(1-\pi)$ is negative it means the whole outcome is negative, making this not a valid probability density function. Am I correct?

$\pi$ here is a parameter taking values in $[0, 1]$, it isn't the number $\pi$.

@QiaochuYuan pi is between 0 and 1, see edit

Then your argument about $1-\pi$ being negative loses its meaning.

I think I should use the second condition that being that the sum of the probability is 1 and use the Taylor expansion I need help with that

This is a probability mass function.

$$ P(X=0) = \pi + (1-\pi) e^{-\lambda}, \qquad P(X=k) = (1-\pi) \frac{ \lambda^k e^{-\lambda} }{k!} $$
First, since $\lambda > 0$ and $0 \leq pi \leq 1$, you can easily check that this function is non-negative.
Second, the values should sum up to $1$. You find that
$$
    \sum_{k \geq 1} P(X=k) 
    = 
    (1-\pi) e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{ \lambda^k }{k!}
    .
$$
You should know how to simplify the last sum. Note we this is only the sum of terms starting at $k = 1$. Finally, you can easily compute
$$
    \sum_{k \geq 0} P(X=k) = P(X=0) + \sum_{k \geq 1} P(X=k).
$$
